# Dropwizard and SSL

Tags: ssl, configuration, https, dropwizard

I cannot seem to configure Dropwizard to use ssl.

I've created a key

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
```

and a certificate

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -days 365 -out server.crt -x509
```

and imported it into a keystore

```
keytool -import -file server.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

From there, I've placed the keystore.jks file into /src/main/resources, alongside the config.yaml file for dropwizard.

Then I tried configuring ssl for dropwizard according to the manual:

```
http:
  ssl:
    keyStore: ./keystore.jks
    keyStorePassword: ********
```

However, when I navigate to the login page, it only works without https: and gives Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error when using https.

Are there other steps that I'm missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I posted on the mailing list and Codahale was quick to respond. I hadn't set nonblocking+ssl connectors in my configuration yaml file under the http: section. Putting in

```
connectorType: nonblocking+ssl
```

fixed everything. Thanks dropwizard wizard!